# Declaring ArrayList of InnerClass

Tags: java

Please let me know what am I missing here

```
public static ArrayList<SearchList> searchlist = new ArrayList<SearchList>();
public static ArrayList<SearchList.SearchResults> resultslist = searchlist.new ArrayList<SearchResults>();
```

I have a Class SearchList with 2 fields, I have get and set methods for those fields, and in this class there is an inner class SearchResults which has 4 fields with respective get and set methods.

Logic: I take 2 fields of SearchList and input it in form and click on Submit. On Submit multiple rows results are displayed which I want to store in the SearchResults 4 fields. So repetivitely I want to enter 2 fields and capture the results which are multiple rows.

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't have an inner class called `ArrayList`, which is what your syntax would require.

Comment: Hi Andy, please can you edit and put the correct syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArrayList` doesn't have an inner class called `ArrayList`, which is what your syntax would require.

You are making it more complicated than necessary: just use the diamond operator.

```
public static ArrayList<SearchList.SearchResults> resultslist = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or, if you're still stuck before Java 7:

```
public static ArrayList<SearchList.SearchResults> resultslist =
    new ArrayList<SearchList.SearchResults>();
```

Comment: sidenote: also declare it as `List` and not `ArrayList`. You most likely wont care for the exact implemenation.

Comment: @KevinEsche that's just a trifling detail compared to the problems with global mutable state...